# How do I get all of the social links onto one line?

Tags: moderncv

I have a resume that I'm building in LaTeX. On my resume, under my name is the contact / social personal info. It puts the social info on two lines, with github being on the second line by itself, even though there's enough room for the github on the same line as the rest.

Is there a way to force the personal info (excluding Name, Address) to be all on one line? I'm using ModernCV and banking style.

Here's an example of what I have:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}   

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\nopagenumbers{}                            

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.92]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{import}

% personal data
\name{Firstname}{Lastname}
\phone[mobile]{999-999-9999} 
\social[linkedin]{linked-in-name}
\social[github]{github-name}
\email{email@gmail.com}     
\homepage{my.website.io}    


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The header under [`moderncv`](//ctan.org/pkg/moderncv)'s `banking` style is [`moderncvheaderiii.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvheadiii.sty). This header is set within a fixed-width `0.8\textwidth` block (hard-coded). You can patch `\makehead` to increase the header width; add the following to your preamble after `\moderncvstyle{banking}`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\makehead}% <cmd>
  {0.8\textwidth}% <search>
  {\textwidth}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
```

[image]

The above patch increases the box width from `0.8\textwidth` to `\textwidth`.